# Trying to understand velocity addition and time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation, faster-than-light

I'm familiar with Einstein's formulae $V=\frac{u+v}{1+ \frac{uv}{c^2}}$ and $\Delta t'=\frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$, the former being velocity addition and the latter being time dilation. Each of these equations imply that you can't go faster than light; the former cannot exceed $c$, and the latter will give an imaginary number in the denominator if you try.

But *why* are these formulae true? I understand it numerically, but how would you explain this *conceptually*?

Comment: What sort of answer do you expect to a "why" question?  If you look at how the equations are derived you will have the best answer you can get.

Comment: @m4r35n357 That would be fine as an answer. But I don't understand the derivation.

Answer (score -1):

The key concept is: space-time is 4 dimensional Minkowski space, and *not* 3 dimensional Euclidean space with a universal time parameter for all.

Comment: English please?

Comment: @DonielFwhat do you mean by "conceptually", then?

Comment: Explaining what you mean by a "4-dimensional Minkowski space," etc., for starters...

Comment: @DonielF There are plenty of explanations out there, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space the key conceptual point is that time is not a universal parameter that ticks uniformly for everyone, it's part of space-time. With that, the formulae make complete sense.

Comment: So...why didn't you include that in your answer? At least the link?